# Saving data incrementaly with python

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a project in which a lot of data is being generated. I want a way to save my data as I go so I don't have to keep it all in RAM. I am currently using numpy to save everything in a npz file when the program finishes. The things that need to be saved are scalars, list, and list of lists. The lists have values added on to them incrementally and so I need a way to append to each list without having to load everything into memory.

I am still a bit new to python so if there is a standard way of doing this please point me in that direction.

Thanks

Comment: not sure what exactly you want in terms of "saving" but pickle is a good library for quickly dumping your scalar variables at least. you could dump your lists as well, but pickle (afaik) doesn't solve your problem of needing to append without loading everything into memory

Comment: if it's part of dataframe, I'm not sure how you can avoid manipulating in memory, except maybe reading only certain rows for it to be manipulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PyTables** is a `numpy` friendly package that is designed to page data to disk to operate on data-sets that don't fit in memory.

See: https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/tutorials.html

https://kastnerkyle.github.io/posts/using-pytables-for-larger-than-ram-data-processing/

## Usage

```
# Create a data-frame description (called a table)
# each attribute of Particle below is a column.
from tables import *
class Particle(IsDescription):
    name      = StringCol(16)   # 16-character String
    idnumber  = Int64Col()      # Signed 64-bit integer
    ADCcount  = UInt16Col()     # Unsigned short integer
    TDCcount  = UInt8Col()      # unsigned byte
    grid_i    = Int32Col()      # 32-bit integer
    grid_j    = Int32Col()      # 32-bit integer
    pressure  = Float32Col()    # float  (single-precision)
    energy    = Float64Col()    # double (double-precision)

# create a hdf5 file on disk to store data in
h5file = open_file("tutorial1.h5", mode="w", title="Test file")

# create a table within the file, using the Particle description class
table = h5file.create_table(group, 'readout', Particle, "Readout example")
```

## Performance

It is especially useful for computations across many data rows.

PyTables supports Blosc (which is a neat trick)

You can perform "in kernal" queries using blosc with the `where` method.

```
result = [row['col2'] for row in table.where(
            '''(((col4 >= lim1) & (col4 < lim2)) |
               ((col2 > lim3) & (col2 < lim4)) &
               ((col1+3.1*col2+col3*col4) > lim5))''')]
```

[image]

[image]